Get Facebook custom or standard events configured to an app
I am trying to create an APP ENGAGEMENT campaign using Facebook ads API. I want to optimize (performance goal) the adset based on custom/standard events associated with the app; not based on clicks or app installs.
I am setting optimization_goal as OFFSITE_CONVERSIONS. Inorder to pass promoted_object, the event name is required. Promoted object will be passed as
{
   "application_id" : <APP_ID>,
   "object_store_url" : <APP_URL>,
   "custom_event_type" : <EVENT_TYPE>
}

In Ads manager UI; when I select the app all the events associated with app are displayed. If no events are associated with the app, it's asking to create an event. How to get all these events via Ads API?

